# Web deployment: Exclude directories depending on Project Configuration name

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, web-deployment-project, msdeploy

I want to delete some image resources depending on what build I'm releasing using MsDeploy.
I have three builds for different clients which are basicly another theme and a lot of configuration transforms to setup their environments correctly.

I don´t want to include the image resources for client1 when deploying to client2.

Been using [this as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747081/how-do-you-include-additional-files-using-vs2010-web-deployment-packages) for making my first stumbling steps into customizing msdeploy and it works good but I have no idea what variable to get the configuration name.

```
In pseudo code:
if $configurationName == "client1"
  exclude dirs gfx/client2 and gfx/client3
if $configurationName == "client2"
  exclude dirs gfx/client1, gfx/client3
and so on...
```

May be its even possible to exclude all and then include just the one which is needed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have posted an entry on my blog about this at http://sedodream.com/2010/08/15/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployHowToExcludeFilesFromPackageBasedOnConfiguration.aspx. Here is the summary:

You use the same approach as in my previous answer, ExcludeFromPackageFiles but you just put a condition on it. So if you have files under *scripts* folder with *'debug'* in the file name that you want to exclude from any package which not built under debug configuration the way you do it is

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)'!='Debug' ">
  <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="scripts\**\*debug*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

More details on my blog, but its a simple mod to the previous approach.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for both your answers. I fixed everything now, struggled alot with including a build and migration for my database (migrator.net) but I cheated and did it through the runcommand instead.

I thought I post my whole deployment process here so people who read this post might learn from all my misstakes.
The basic steps are:

- Web.config transforms to make sure all settings are correct for each of the clients
- Backup of webserver files and database at the production server
- Exclude all gfx directories for all clients
- Include the gfx dir which is wanted by this client
- Include extra binares and license-files which are not referenced by the project correclty
- Migrate the database to the current revision
- Webdeploy all the new files

Deploy.proj, imported by `<Import Project="Deploy.csproj" />` at the last line of the webproject project file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
            ExcludeAllGfx;

            Client1Backup;
            Client1Include;
            Client1Migrate;

            CollectBinFiles;
            $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
        </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="ExcludeAllGfx" BeforeTargets="ExcludeFilesFromPackage">
        <ItemGroup>
            <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="gfx\client1\**\*.*">
                <FromTarget>Project</FromTarget>
            </ExcludeFromPackageFiles>
            <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="gfx\client2\**\*.*">
                <FromTarget>Project</FromTarget>
            </ExcludeFromPackageFiles>
            <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="gfx\client3\**\*.*">
                <FromTarget>Project</FromTarget>
            </ExcludeFromPackageFiles>
        </ItemGroup>
        <Message Text="ExcludeFromPackageFiles: @(ExcludeFromPackageFiles)" Importance="high" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="CollectBinFiles">
        <ItemGroup>
            <_CustomFiles Include="..\IncludeBin\Telerik\Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll" />
            <_CustomFiles Include="..\IncludeBin\Telerik\Telerik.Reporting.dll" />
            <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
                <DestinationRelativePath>Bin\%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
            </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Client1Migrate" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release Client1|AnyCPU'">
        <Exec Command="&quot;..\MigratorProject\Bats\Client1.bat&quot;" ContinueOnError="false" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Client1Include" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release Client1|AnyCPU'">
        <ItemGroup>
            <_CustomFilesClient1 Include="gfx\Client1\**\*.*" Exclude="gfx\Client1\**\.svn\**\*.*">
                <FromTarget>Project</FromTarget>
            </_CustomFilesClient1>
            <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFilesClient1.Identity)">
                <DestinationRelativePath>gfx\client1\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
            </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Client1Backup" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release Client1|AnyCPU'">
        <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe&quot; -verb:sync -source:contentPath=&quot;page of client1&quot;,computerName=http://10.8.1.1/MsDeployAgentService2,encryptPassword=pass -dest:package=c:\Backups\deployments\client1.zip,computerName=http://10.8.1.1/MsDeployAgentService2,encryptPassword=pass" ContinueOnError="false" />
        <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe&quot; -verb:sync -source:runCommand='C:\Backups\deployments\scripts\backup.cmd client1',waitInterval=20000 -dest:auto,computerName=http://10.8.1.1/MsDeployAgentService2,encryptPassword=pass" ContinueOnError="false" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Backup.cmd:

```
@echo off
sqlcmd -v name=%1 -S . -i "C:\Backups\deployments\scripts\backupdb.sql"
C:\Backups\deployments\scripts\stampme "C:\Backups\deployments\%1.zip"
```

backupdb.sql:

```
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(50) -- database name 
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files 
DECLARE @fileName NVARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup 
DECLARE @fileDate NVARCHAR(20) -- used for file name 

SET @name = '$(name)'
SET @path = 'C:\Backups\deployments\' 
SELECT @fileDate = REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),120),':','-'), ' ', '@')
SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK' 
BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName;
```

stampme.bat: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-stampme.html

Hope anyone gets some help and examples from this entry.

Comment: "Include extra binares and license-files which are not referenced by the project correclty" -> just add them to the project set to copy to output.

Comment: Yes but licenses is different for Developing machines and staging/production servers, thats why I dont even want them in the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend Sayed's examples using the `Condition` attribute on your [`ItemGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/646dk05y.aspx), and the `$(Configuration)` property.

e.g.:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="a.jpeg" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Client1' " />
</ItemGroup>
```