# How can I include (and execute) deploy related tools in an MSDeploy package without making them part of my app?

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

I'm starting to use MSDeploy quite aggressively within our Visual studio web projects projects as a mechanism for producing self contained build artefacts that have everything needed to setup and run themselves on a remote server.  This works fine for simple web apps, however we have some web applications that need additional command line tools to be run on the remote servers before the application can be considered to be "deployed".

I have followed [Sayed's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747081/how-do-you-include-additional-files-using-vs2010-web-deployment-packages) to include additional files and folders within my package, but they appear as a subfolder within the deploy of my web application (and that's not good, as the files are only needed once at deploy time).

Ideally, I'd like the package.zip to contain the tools as a set of sibling folders to the IIS aplication, and have a mechanism to run an exe within those folders at deploy time.  (I think this is via the deploy.manifest, but would like advice here too) but NOT actually leave the files on the remote machine.

Comment: I've abandoned this.  The runCommand provider is shaky (waitAttempts and waitInterval settings don't seem to work) and I can't figure out how to transform the runCommand "path" to the correct deployed path.  I use powershell Invoke-Command to run the remote EXE instead.  As for making the package a sibling to the webapp, I've abandoned that too: I'm only using the packages for internal testing so no biggy if the EXE is a subfolder.  MsDeploy looks promising, but there is just not enough beginner docs to get going and MSBuild integration is voodoo....