# How to include custom files into Deployment Package for ASP.NET MVC 3 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, msdeploy

We are using **msdeploy** (from VS 2010) to **build deployment package** of our web project. The problem is that we'd like to **include our custom file** (for this scenario it is app_config.htm "template" file which will be used for maintenance mode) into that package.

Is it somehow possible to include such kind of custom file into the deployment package ??

In the project properties, section `Package/Publish web` -> `Items to deploy` we prefer the option `Only files needed to run this application`. We don't want to include all files only because of this one (app_offline.html.template) we want to have there.

**EDIT** solution found  here: [How do you include additional files using VS2010 web deployment packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747081/how-do-you-include-additional-files-using-vs2010-web-deployment-packages)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [KwateeSDCM](http://sdcm.kwatee.net). It's got a pretty good mechanism for overriding standard package (web applications) files with versions that can be customized according to the target server and/or version.

Comment: KwateeSDCM does look interesting, but it doesn't really answer the question.