# Visual Studio: How to automatically copy custom file to output directory only when publish website?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, publish, msdeploy

I got some files necessary for the hosting environment, e.g: robots.txt as in the attached image.

But I don't want to store them in Visual Studio solution, because they are not a part of my project, it will be confusing to have these under the solution folder or source control.

So, I am thinking is there anyway to let Visual Studio automatically copy these files from my custom location (e.g: D:\HostingPrepareForST\ ) to the output folder when I hit "Publish" to publish the website?

[image]

Comment: That's for VS 2010 but I think you can get it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747081/how-do-you-include-additional-files-using-vs2010-web-deployment-packages