# VS publish vs dotless

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When Visual Studio publish feature is used, it does not publish the css files created by dotless.

E.g. I have a less style sheet named Site.less and upon build it will create Site.css. However as the Style.css file is not included in the project it will not get published.

Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: You could use the httphandler. That would JIT the less. You could look into T4 transforms for less.

Comment: Why not you included that style.css in the project?

Comment: Solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747081/how-do-you-include-additional-files-using-vs2010-web-deployment-packages

Answer (score 0):

Found it...http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/01/t4-template-for-less-css.aspx

Add this template to you project. It will compile on change rather than on build.

Comment: Idea sounds good but I have another problem.
I am using TFS and I dont want the generated css to be added to TFS.

Comment: Then don't check it in.

Comment: I don't want to be worried about that. Any other ideas?

Comment: Solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747081/how-do-you-include-additional-files-using-vs2010-web-deployment-packages