# Including extra files on deploy

Tags: msbuild

I need to include a folder and the files in it into the deployment process.This folder isn't part of the project. This folder is created on the build server. I cannot include this files in the project.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747081/how-do-you-include-additional-files-using-vs2010-web-deployment-packages/2748752#2748752) very helpful.

I've edited my web application csproj file and added this to the end of the file

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>CustomCollectFiles;$(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);</CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>CustomCollectFiles;$(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);</CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>   
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup> 
      <_CustomFiles Include="Workspace\build\**\*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>Workspace\build</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

It should include all files from the folder `Workspace\build` and place it in the deployment directory in the same place.

But unfortunately it's not working. I'm not very good with msbuild, so I guess I'm missing something here.

Comment: When you say it's not working, do you mean your custom target CustomCollectFiles is not being called or is it being called but your files still aren't being included?

Comment: did you try using PipelineCollectFilesPhaseDependsOn already?

Comment: cokeman: It is being called, but my files aren't included.

Comment: Felix Lahmer: It works! Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

For example, given that your files are in a directory called `build` which is on the same directory level as the solution directory you can do it like this:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <CreateItem Include="$(SolutionDir)..\build\**\*.*">
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="AdditionalFiles" />
    </CreateItem>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(AdditionalFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)build" />
</Target>
```

This would copy those files in `$(SolutionDir)..\build` to the `build` subdirectory of the output directory `$(TargetDir)build` whenever the solution is built. Modify the `Include` mask, `DestinationFolder` and build target name to suit your needs.

Comment: The thing is I need to copy these files only on deployment. Not on every build.

Answer (score 0):

See http://sedodream.com/2012/10/09/VSWebPublishHowToIncludeFilesOutsideOfTheProjectToBePublished.aspx

This only works for file deployments (not MSDeploy).