# How do you include additional files for web publishing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, web-deployment, msdeploy

I am attempting to use a build project to publish files from TFS to our web server. I don't have a project file as these are html, text, js files managed outside of Visual Studio. The basis for my attempt was [How do you include additional files using VS2010 web deployment packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747081/how-do-you-include-additional-files-using-vs2010-web-deployment-packages) and while the status of the build is successful, the files never get published to the server. Has anyone every used Web Publishing to push files maintained in TFS to a server like this. I want to use the standard publishing targets so the builds are easy to maintain ongoing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tooling in Visual Studio that builds Web Deployment packages requires a Web Application Project.

I suggest creating a Web Application project and adding your html/js files to it, then the default publish targets should be able to build a web deploy package and publish it without problem.

Comment: Dylan, this is more of a comment than a full answer, at least so far.

Comment: edited the answer to be a suggestion rather than a question.  Not sure if this makes it better.