# How do I include dynamically loaded assemblies in azure website deployment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, .net-assembly

I have an ASP.Net application that uses several assemblies that are not loaded until runtime.  Application worked fine on local system but when I deploy it on Azure it does not contain that un-referenced assemblies.  What is the best way to include un-referenced assemblies in the Azure website deployment package?

Comment: How are they referenced in your project?  Can you not simply reference the assemblies, and set the `Copy Local` flag to true?

Comment: These are not referenced in my project. I want to load them dynamically based on some criteria. I don't want to reference them in my project. I believe there must be some way to do it without referencing. Looking some better solution to handle this situation.

Comment: Does a post-build step copying the files to, say, the bin folder work?

Comment: Nope, It does not add assemblies to the Azure package.

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747081/how-do-you-include-additional-files-using-vs2010-web-deployment-packages