# How do you publish Class Libraries in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ftp

I have a `MVC` web application that I am developing in Visual Studio 2010. Along side my `MVC` project in my solution I also have 2 `Class Library` projects.

When I right click the MVC project in the solution explorer I get (among others) these options: `Build Deployment Package`, `Publish...`, and `Package/Publish Settings`.

These options are not available for the 2 `Class Library` projects, so prior to uploading any code I am currently putting everything in a deployment folder on my local machine using the `Publish...` option for the `MVC` project and just copy & pasting the other 2 projects in windows explorer.

I would very much like to use the `Publish...` option to deploy all 3 projects using FTP to our server.

I have discovered that if I change the `Output Type` of the 2 `Class Library` projects from `Class Library` to `Console Application` then I get the options to `Publish...` etc., but they aren't `Console Applications`s so I don't really want to do this.

My question is, how can I , using Visual Studio 2010 publish `Class Library` projects using FTP?

**UPDATE**
Turns out I'm a numpty!

Because the MVC app references the 2 class libraries, the `.dll`s for them are already included in the bin folder for the MVC app and I didn't need to include the other projects when I publish.

Comment: Are the class libraries referenced by the MVC project?

Comment: yes they are referenced by the MVC project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't need to separately publish the class library projects. When you publish the MVC project it will include any references the project has. As your MVC project references the 2 class library projects, when you publish it the class libraries will be included.

Comment: You are quite correct, I think at some point in the past I started to do it the way I described and never tried it without adding the 2 project folders manually. I just deleted them and everything works fine because the `.dll`s for the class libraries are in the MVC apps `bin` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Might this one help

1. Change Solution Configuration to Release mode (by default it may be    debug)
2. Click on Solution Explorer and Rebuld the library project.

This will release the dlls to [yourProjectFolder]\bin\Release

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize how deployment process collects files you want to include in your deployment package.

Since your question is about Visual Studio 2010, I've found a Q&A here in StackOverflow that will guide you to the right direction in terms of including additional files (like your class library assemblies) as part of your deployment:

- [How do you include additional files using VS2010 web deployment packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747081/how-do-you-include-additional-files-using-vs2010-web-deployment-packages)