# Azure Web Job Resource Deployment

Tags: web-deployment, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I created a web job which loads a text file from disk
My problem is that i get a `DirectoryNotFoundException` whenever this job executes.

I have a Resources directory and a text file in my web job project
And it work well when i run it locally.

When remote debugging i can see the active directory is `D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\EdisonContinuousMailJob\5rvo4ggm.rqa`
And it contains all the dll, pdb files required for my web job but missing the Resources folder.

How can i make my resources deployed together with my web job ?

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research i found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840167/deploy-subfolders-for-azure-webjob), and the answers suggest that this is a bug and offer a workaround.

For my purposes i embedded the text file in the .Net assembly following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433171/how-to-embed-a-text-file-in-a-net-assembly),
and this works well for me.