# asp.net webapi swagger xmldocument file not copied by octopus deploy

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, teamcity, swagger-ui, octopus-deploy

I have set up swagger for my webapi documentation. I am using Octopus to do the automatic deployment. Though i have specified the XmlDocument path as bin\test.xml in Project-< Properties -> build tab -> Output -> XML Documentation File, octopus deploy is not copying the test.xml inside bin directory on the test server.

I did the changes to the project release using the information from following link

[swagger-ui returns 500 after deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914842/swagger-ui-returns-500-after-deployment)

Can anyone guide me what could be the problem please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me what process you are using to create the NuGet package for Octopus Deploy - Octopack? Is this being done by a build server? Do you mean that the xml file is not in the NuGet package?

Comment: I am using Octopack to create the nuget package. It is done by build server. Yes, it is not in the nuget package. i am expecting the file in bin\test.xml but its not. if i put the file in app_data\test.xml then app_data folder is created inside bin and also separately on the test server.

Comment: Is there a .nuspec file and if so are there any <file> rules? What is the build server? A cheap hack would be to add a bin\test.xml file into your source project and change the build action to content.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you include your xml file when crating nuget package

example from VSO package application step:

[image]