# Error 500 : https://localhost:443/Cufx/swagger/docs/v1 when attempting to view the documentation

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

Folks,

I get the following error when navigating to the documentation url.

```
500 : https://localhost:443/Cufx/swagger/docs/v1
```

I checked that the xml file is created and is in the proper destination path. I also confirmed that the app is also looking for the file in the same path. I looked at the xml file and made sure that it is properly formatted.

I am not sure why else the documentation would not show. How can I get the actual error that swagger is encountering?

Comment: Do you get the base swagger-ui, but without the API docs? or do you get nothing but a 500?

Comment: Correct.  That is exactly what's happening.  Instead of links to the api calls, I get the error message.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914842/swagger-ui-returns-500-after-deployment/33916806#33916806 is not your problem?

Comment: If not the above, Have you set .EnableSwaggerUi("cufx/{*assetPath}", c => ?

Comment: @VisualBean I have made sure that the documentation file is generating and is in the proper path both in the file directory and the app path.  Now, I am not using the EnableSwaggerUI() method. When I added swashbuckle, it had created a class called SwaggerConfig and there is a property that it overrides named IncludeXmlComments.  This accepts the path to the generated documentation file. I have double checked this and make sure it points to the generated xml file.  I am totally clueless on this one.

Comment: I figured it out. I was able to get to the actual error message once I turned on the web api tracing.  It was duplicate methods with the same name issue.