# SwaggerUI doesn't work after I deploy to IIS

Tags: iis, .net-4.0, swagger, swagger-ui

I developed an .net framework WebApi and integrate the SwaggerUI. It works in my local IIS express.

[image]

Then I deploy my project into a local folder `restapi` and I copy this folder to my remote IIS server and configure it. The webpage is running well bet the SwaggerUI doesn't. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

The error message is:

> 500 : {"Message":"An error has occurred."} http://myserver:80/swagger/docs/v1

What could be the reason? Don't know where to start to fix the issue. Can anybody help? Thanks.

By the way, I'm using Swashbuckle 5.0.

Comment: Turn out it's the xml document issue. Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914842/swagger-ui-returns-500-after-deployment