# Unable to connect to azure pipeline, but deploy still works in app service deployment center?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I keep getting this error message in the Azure App service deployment center:

> We were unable to connect to the Azure Pipeline that is connected to
> this Web App. This could mean it has been removed from the Azure Dev
> Ops Portal. If this has happened, you can disconnect this pipeline and
> set up a new deployment pipeline.

The thing is, it stil says that it successfully deploys, but If you try to access swagger for example, you get an HTTP error 500, (swagger does work localy). I have tried restarting the app service, going back commits, to see if that would help, but nothing is working. All Json data has been doubel chekced so that isn't the problem either. Anyone know of a fix?

Comment: what is the url your are trying to access ?

Comment: Look into this SO thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914842/swagger-ui-returns-500-after-deployment#:~:text=As%20stated%20in%20the%20accepted,use%20multiple%20XML%20documentation%20files) once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We were unable to connect to the Azure Pipeline that is connected to  this Web App. This could mean it has been removed from the Azure DevOps Portal. If this has happened, you can disconnect this pipeline and set up a new deployment pipeline.

- Th error says that files are missing in the current build , try with new deployment pipeline.
- You might have added an  ***archive***  step in the build pipeline. This causes the artifact to be zipped before publish.
- In the release pipeline if you use  ***Azure App Service Deploy*** task , This internally uses ***Zip Deploy***, that will zip the files.
- Remove the archive step, the double zipping will be avoided.

> HTTP error 500

- Make sure the XML documentation file output is in *bin* and not in *bin\Debug* or *bin\Release* (verify this for all build configurations).

Comment: Thanks, somehow changing a setting and then reverting it back and then restarting the whole thing made it work