# Swagger API works normally locally but on IIS I get an internal server error after Execute my function

Tags: asp.net, iis

Swagger API works normally locally but on IIS I get an internal server error after Execute my function.

Error image description:

[image: Error image description]

**

```
Updated!!
The issue solved
It was from an invalid certificate
```

**

Comment: [Does this answer useful to u?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914842/swagger-ui-returns-500-after-deployment)

Comment: Let FRT reveal more about that 500 error, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis